# Need help creating SQL query from example of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database table below.

[image: database table]

And I want to get list of all DBKey that have: at least one entry with Staled=1, and the last entry is Staled=0

The list should not contain DBKey that has only Staled=0 OR Staled=1.

In this example, the list would be: DBKey=2 and DBKey=3

Comment: StackOverflow encourages you to show us what you have tried, along with your question. If this criteria is not met, your question will generally be downvoted. So, I suggest you also add your attempts at writing the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.DBKey
FROM TABLE T
WHERE
    -- checks that the DBKey has at least one entry with Staled = 1 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT DISTINCT Staled
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE DBKey = T.DBKey
            AND Staled = 1
        )
    -- checks that the last Staled entry for this DBKey is 0
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT DISTINCT Staled
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE DBKey = T.DBKey
            AND Staled = 0
            AND EntryDateTime = (
                SELECT MAX(EntryDateTime)
                FROM TABLE
                WHERE DBKey = T.DBKey
                )
        )
```

Here is a working [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4274f/5) of the query, using your sample data.

The idea is to use `EXISTS` to look for those individual conditions that you've described. I've added comments to my code to explain what each does.

Comment: Thanks. The SQL query works, I got the correct list. And especially, it is good to understand for learning purposes.

Comment: @ewlung Well, this is the purpose of StackOverflow. Good luck with your queries next time.

Answer (score 1):

Should be done with a simple JOIN... Starting FIRST with any 1 qualifiers, joined to itself by same key AND 0 staled qualifier AND the 0 record has a higher date.  Ensure you have an index on ( DBKey, Staled, EntryDateTime )

```
SELECT
      YT.DBKey,
      MAX( YT.EntryDateTime ) as MaxStaled1,
      MAX( YT2.EntryDateTime ) as MaxStaled0
   from
      YourTable YT
         JOIN YourTable YT2
            ON YT.DBKey = YT2.DBKey
            AND YT2.Staled = 0
            AND YT.EntryDateTime < YT2.EntryDateTime
   where
      YT.Staled = 1
   group by 
      YT.DBKey
   having
      MAX( YT.EntryDateTime ) < MAX( YT2.EntryDateTime )
```

Comment: Still not going to work with the `HAVING` clause. Just [**look here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4274f/2)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, not working SQL Error, or not working wrong results.

Comment: The link and the query at that link works for me, try refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
With X as
(
    Select Row_Number() Over (Partition By DBKey Order By EntryDateTime Desc) RN, DBKey, Staled
    From table
)
Select * 
From X 
Where rn = 1 and staled = 0 and
    Exists (select 1 from x x2 where x2.dbkey = x.dbkey and Staled = 1)
```